# Determine whether the subset of the Euclidean metric space $\mathbb{R}$ is open or closed or both or neither

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, metric-spaces, solution-verification

The interval $[a,b]=\{x \in \mathbb{R} | a \le x \le b \}$ for fixed $a<b \in \mathbb{R}$.

To prove that in the Euclidean metric space $\mathbb{R}$ that every closed interval $[a,b]$ is a closed set, it suffices to show that $(a_n) \to x$, where $x \in [a,b]$. Suppose $(a_n) \in [a,b]$. This means that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, a \le a_n \le b$. Assume for contradiction that $x \notin [a,b]$. Then $x<a$ or $x>b$.

$\cdot$ Case 1 $(x<a)$: Let $\varepsilon=a-x>0$. Since $(a_n) \to x$, then $\exists N \in \mathbb{N} \ni \forall n \ge N$, we have  $d(a_n,x)=|a_n-x|<a-x$. This means that $x-\varepsilon<a_n<x+\varepsilon$. So $a_n<x+\varepsilon=x+(a-x)=a \Rightarrow a_n<a$. However, this contradicts the premise that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, a \le a_n \le b$.

$\cdot$ Case 2 ($x>b$): Let $\varepsilon=x-b>0$. Since $(a_n) \to x$, then $\exists N \in \mathbb{N} \ni \forall n \ge N$, we have  $d(a_n,x)=|a_n-x|<x-b$. This means that $x-\varepsilon<a_n<\varepsilon+x$. So $a_n>x-\varepsilon=x-(x-b)=b \Rightarrow a_n>b$. However, this contradicts the premise that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, a \le a_n \le b$.

Therefore, $x \in [a,b]$.

Second proof:

Suppose $(a_n) \in [a,b]$ such that $(a_n) \to c$. Then $a \le a_n \le b$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Choose $N \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $n \ge N$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $\forall \varepsilon >0$ we have $d(a_n,c)=|a_n-c|<\varepsilon$. Now, $|a_n-c|<\varepsilon$ for every $\varepsilon \in (0,\infty)$ if and only if $a_n-c=0 \Rightarrow a_n=c$. Thus $a \le c \le b$, and hence $c \in [a,b]$.

Are both proofs correct?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: It useful  that $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges to $x$ iff $\{n\in \Bbb N: a_n\not\in J\}$ is finite whenever $J$ is an open interval with $x\in J$. In your 1st proof, if the $set$ $\{a_n: n\in\Bbb N\}\subset [a,b]$ and if $x\not\in [a,b]$, let $r=\min(|x-a|,|x-b|)$. Let $J=(x-r,x+r).$ Then $x\in J$ and  $J$ is disjoint from $[a,b]$ so $  \{n\in \Bbb N: a_n\not \in J\}=\Bbb N$ is not finite, so $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ does not converge to $x.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Would you please show me a proof of "$(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $x$ iff $\{n\in \Bbb N: a_n\not\in J\}$ is finite whenever $J$ is an open interval with $x \in J$".

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=x \iff$ $ \forall e>0\,\exists m\in\Bbb N\,\forall n>m\,(|a_n-x|<e)\iff $ $ \forall e>0\,\exists m\in\Bbb N\,(\{n\in\Bbb N:|a_n-x|\ge e\}\subset \{n\in\Bbb N:n\le m\}\,)\iff$ $ \forall e>0\,(\{n\in\Bbb N:|a_n-x|\ge e\}$ is finite).... Now let $J$ be an open interval with $x\in J.$ There exist $e_1,e_2$ with $xe_1,x+e_1)\subset J\subset (x-e_2,x+e_2).$ Therefore (i) if $a_n\to x$ then $\{n: a_n\not\in J\}$ is a subset of the finite set $\{n: |x-a_n|<e_2\},$ and (ii) $continued...$

Comment: $continued....$ (ii) if $\neg (a_n\to x)$ then there exists $e_3>0$ such that $\{n: |a_n-x|>e_3\}$ is infinite, so there does exist some open interval $I$ with $x\in I$ such that $\{n:a_n\not\in I\}$ is infinite, namely $I=(x-e_3,x+e_3).$... I want to improve part 1 of this but I'm out of edit-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first proof is fine, though a bit tedious. You can also say that $\Bbb R \setminus [a,b] = (\leftarrow,a) \cup (b, \rightarrow)$ which is a union of open intervals hence open so $[a,b]$ is closed.

The second "proof" is nonsense: you cannot choose such an $N$,  except $N=0$.

Comment: But if $N=0$ works, why is this nonsense? My understanding is that to show that a sequence converges to some number, we need only to show that $\forall \varepsilon \in (0,\infty)$ we can find a natural number $N$ for which every natural number $n \ge N$ implies $d(a_n,c)<\varepsilon$?

Comment: @Karam you don't start with $\varepsilon$ but with $N$, which depends on $\varepsilon$!

Comment: So if I had written let $\varepsilon \in (0,\infty)$. Then choose $N$.. would that work?

Comment: @Karam It depends on the $\varepsilon$; but I don't think you can pick one to prove $c \in [a,b]$, though, and then you're back to proof 1, by contradiction.